# Issues with using side by side AutoMapper versions

Tags: .net, automapper, app-config, .net-assembly

I have an application in which I want to use the latest version of AutoMapper. I am also using a third-party assembly which itself uses AutoMapper 3.1.1.0.

If I allow the third-party assembly to use the latest version, it attempts to invoke a method which no longer exists and I get this:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Sif.Framework.Service.Mapper.MapperFactory' threw an exception.'
Inner Exception
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'AutoMapper.IMappingExpression`2<!!0,!!1> AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap()'.
```

I therefore placed the 3.1.1.0 DLLs in a sub-folder and referenced them like this. I put them in a directory off in a weird location to ensure the codeBase directive is actually working and it's not that the assembly is being loaded by other means.

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="AutoMapper" publicKeyToken="be96cd2c38ef1005" culture="neutral" />
        <codeBase version="3.1.1.0" href="C:\OldAutomapper\AutoMapper.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="AutoMapper.Net4" publicKeyToken="be96cd2c38ef1005" culture="neutral" />
        <codeBase version="3.1.1.0" href="C:\OldAutomapper\AutoMapper.Net4.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

If I remove my reference to the 6.x DLL from my application and comment out the code which uses it, this works. The third-party DLL picks up the reference and functions normally.

If I then add the 6.x DLL back to the project, it still works. Hey, we're getting somewhere!

But then when I uncomment my code that uses AutoMapper, it throws the TypeInitializationException again. Note that simply referencing AutoMapper in my code is enough to do this, none of it has to be executed at runtime. I can comment out everything except a Profile class, never actually load the Profile, and it still breaks the third party assembly.

Any ideas what is going on here?

Edit: I realized I should mention that I'm aware that the NuGet install of AutoMapper adds a `bindingRedirect` to app.config which makes all versions of AutoMapper redirect to the newly installed version. I remove this redirect from my config files after installing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. The problem is that starting in .NET 4.5.1 and only for traditional desktop applications, [Visual Studio ignores what you put in app.config and quietly adds its own bindingRedirect to the output config file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Automatic
>   binding redirects are enabled by default for traditional desktop apps
>   that target the .NET Framework 4.5.1 and later versions. The binding
>   redirects are added to the output configuration (app.config) file when
>   the app is compiled and overrides the assembly unification that might
>   otherwise take place. The source app.config file is not modified.

Gee, thanks guys. If you're going to silently modify my config files, you could at least modify the source one so I can tell it's happening.

Once I turned off automatic binding redirection, it worked.